# How do I fix width/height of rotated img/div?

Tags: html, css

This example shows 2 div one without rotation the other with. The rotated image blocks the text. How do I rewrite this so the text isn't covered up?

```css
.Rotate {
  transform: translate(0, -100%) rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://farm4.static.flickr.com/3010/4566263938_a56f24a24f.jpg"> <br/>
Can you see me?
</div>
<div>
<img class="Rotate" src="https://farm4.static.flickr.com/3010/4566263938_a56f24a24f.jpg"> <br/>
Can you see me?
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transforms are purely visual...any wrapper stays the same size and the browser remembers where the images were and allocates space for it.

Wrap the image in a div the right size **after** translation and it'll be fine.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 300px;
  height: 460px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
img {
  transform: translate(0, -100%) rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="" />
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why doesn't it seem to work for me? https://jsfiddle.net/rbu669my/3/ Do I need to know the rotated width and height? I thought the wrapper would fix it dynamically

Comment: No, as I said, the wrapper won't adjust dynamically...transforms are purely visual. The boxes stay exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could use margin to align this.

```css
.Rotate {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin:100px -90px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://farm4.static.flickr.com/3010/4566263938_a56f24a24f.jpg"> <br/>
Can you see me?
</div>
<div>
<img class="Rotate" src="https://farm4.static.flickr.com/3010/4566263938_a56f24a24f.jpg"> <br/>
Can you see me?
</div>
```